# unable to use Cinnamon GUI as a windowed environment

Tags: cinnamon, powershell

What am I doing wrong or what have I forgotten? I wanted to be able to use WSL2 to have floating windows, able to co-exist with Windows' own floating windows (resizeable, etc) while opening the Linux windows as apps from Cinnamon desktop (also a floating window). I installed WSL2 without incident (using PowerShell commands) where it defaulted to installing Ubuntu, including update and upgrade using sudo. I wanted the Cinnamon GUI, since it is closer to Windows 11 convention than GNOME is, so I went through that install, too (asking for the complete install with programs, following instructions; took a long time).Everything seemed OK. But it says that all I needed to do was to open Ubuntu as an icon from the Windows menu. Along the way, I created a username and password without incident. I HAVE the Ubuntu icon, but when I click it I get a command window with linuxusername@DELL:~1.I type Ubuntu and "command not found". I try wsl --ubuntu and I'm told I can use sudo apt install wsl (but I have already installed wsl!). From linuxusername@DELL I CAN type simple applications' names (like xcalc) and I do get a floating window with normal controls available; but typing LibreOffice Writer gets me a command not found at that prompt. Looking at Windows listing of programs, I see a whole bunch of Linux programs being available, and if I click, I get the program to start (like LibreOffice Draw) but ONLY as full screen with no ability to make smaller; only an "X" to close). OK, so maybe I need to exit and go back to PowerShell and type "ubuntu" there? Well, no, that just gets me back to linuxusername@DELL:~$ prompt. I THOUUGHT I could have the Ubuntu (Cinnamon) control panel open up as a floating window and then click inside there to open up any Linux program listed, and those would also open up as a separate floating window, separate from the Cinnamon window. In other words, NOT having to use typed commands, but using the GUI and having all of the Linux windows being just like Windows programs, all with their own abilty to move, be resized, etc. So, where did I fail? Is there something about X-Windows I forgot (I didn't see anything about that). Is what I wanted just not possible (it sounded like that was the whole idea pf how WSL2 was supposed to work). Yes, I KNOW I could use virtualbox, but that means all the Linux programs are confined "inside" the Cinnamon/Ubuntu main box, not each one separately able to float alongside Windows applications. And virtualbox is a bit of overkill and needing more setup work. I have to believe what I wanted to happen IS possible, but I've missed something? HELP!

Comment: What does the command: `sudo systemctl start lightdm` do?

Comment: If `lightdm` is installed, and if you also have the capability to run graphical user interface applications, then it should start up and then you should see a login window which should forward you to cinnamon. If it says that lightdm is not installed, then run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install ubuntucinnamon-desktop` and when that's done installing, run `sudo systemctl start lightdm` and again, it should open a login window and after you login, that should take you to the cinnamon desktop.

Comment: Also, linux is case sensitive unlike windows. So commands will rarely if ever have capital letters. [According to the file list of the libreoffice-writer package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libreoffice-writer/filelist), the command for libreoffice-writer should be `lowriter` as that is the name of the file under the `/bin/` directory.

Comment: Please provide release details; are you hoping we guess  (*software changes over time & thus differences maybe involved; being specific with details allows us to be accurate with advice*)

Comment: OK, sudo systemctl start lightdm did nothing -- no error message, but nothing seemed to happen -- so I did sudo apt update and it did a bit of "housekeeping" (all this at the myusername@DELL:~$ prompt under PowerShell. The command sudo apt install ubuntucinnamon-desktop just gets an error message about not being found. (And not sure I need it since I entered a similar command yesterday and it went through a long process of adding files, but without incident. Entering sudo systemctl start lightdm did nothing. I entered password as requested; nothing happened. "Lowriter" DID work for a window.